# "drush config-split:export" returns "Not enough arguments (missing: 'split')."

Tags: drush

I recently upgraded from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9. I've used `drush config-split:export` (`drush csex`) quite often. After the upgrade, it keeps throwing an error which is very vague.

> Not enough arguments (missing: "split")

No documentation says what the problem is, nor what that argument should be.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can just run `drush config:export`. Very old versions required explicitly calling a config split

Comment: Isn't it just missing the split's name? Like `drush config-split:export MYSPLIT`? Run `drush help config-split:export`.

Comment: The example of usage for the command is `drush config-split:export development`, which is said to _Export configuration of the "development" split_.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use config-split:export with Drupal 9, make sure you go to admin/config/development/configuration/config-split. There you should see if you already have a split configuration and use machine name: drush config-split:export [machine_name]